# background color on html and why fullscreen

Tags: css

I have a background color on the html tag, then the color will fill in the browser.But i call

```
getComputedStyle(document.docuemntElement).height
```

and get **20px**;

1. Why it will fill the browser when html has no border and no padding?
2. then i call `getComputedStyle(document.docuemntElement).clientHeight`, and get **768px**; and i refer to MDN, clientHeight is equal to content height and padding. how it be calculated?

Comment: `docuemntElement` should probably be `documentElement`.

Comment: @connexo you are correct, but I don't think OP understands the typo. Two and a half hours after your comment, OP reedits an edit but neither corrects or acknowledges the typo.

Answer (score 1):

background colors applied to the html tag are always fullscreen.

you should add the background color to your body tag. Then it will only be as big as the content of your page

if you look at this snippet you will see the difference

```css
html{
  background-color:green;
}

body{
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <body>
  </body>
</html>
```